# should I write multiple adapters for similar recycler views in android studio?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want to create different recycler views in my app. They are all very similar, as every recycler view is using the same data. Only the design changed.
Is it better to use multiple adapters or to just create one adapter and let this adapter handle different views ?

Comment: Maybe you need to research "ViewType"

Answer (score 1):

Generally it's better to keep your code clean and simple. if you have same functionality with different views, it's better to have one adapter with different view types.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends - you could have unique adapters for each representation, you could have an abstract class with the general functionality where you need to implement some custom display method in each subclass, or you could pass in an object that handles displaying things a certain way - or you could just have one adapter with some options, and depending on the options you show this or that, load this layout or that one, whatever

Which one you go with depends on your code - the idea with cutting down on repetition is to make it easier to read and maintain. If the representations are all fairly different (doesn't matter if they're using the same data, it's what you have to do with it) then one big adapter with lots of conditional stuff to handle them all is going to be complex - and hard to work with if you need to add another type of display

Individual adapters is simplest, but it's a lot of wasted code if they're all mostly the same thing repeated - and harder to maintain.

I like the composition thing personally, having something you delegate the actual display stuff to, so there's one adapter and one presentation component you hand in to make it look one way or another. But again, that might be overcomplicating things

Don't make your life hard! And don't make something adaptable just because you might want to adapt it and reuse it in future - most of the time, you never will, so don't give yourself more work than you need to do right now